# How to handle page reload in AngularJS app for URL that doesn't exist in Laravel routes

Tags: angularjs, laravel-5, url-routing

Am using Larvel 5 at server-side and AngularJs at client-side.

So I have these routes in AngularJS:

```
var adminApp = angular
  .module('adminApp', [
    'ngRoute',
    'ngResource'
  ])
  .config(['$httpProvider', '$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
  function($httpProvider, $routeProvider, $locationProvider)
  {

      $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"] = 'XMLHttpRequest';

      $routeProvider
      .when('/admin', {
          templateUrl: 'ng/templates/home/dashboard.html',
          controller: 'HomeController'
      })
      .when('/admin/users', {
          templateUrl: 'ng/templates/user/users.html',
          controller: 'UserController'
      })
      .otherwise({
          redirectTo: '/'
      });


      if(window.history && window.history.pushState){
          $locationProvider.html5Mode({
              enabled    : true,
              requireBase: false
          });
      };

  }]);
```

An in  Laravel I have this:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function()
{
    Route::get('/',[
        'uses' => 'Admin\HomeController@getIndex',
        'as'   => 'admin.home.getIndex'
    ]);


    Route::get('/users',[
        'uses' => 'Admin\UserController@getIndex',
        'as'   => 'admin.users.getIndex'
    ]);

    Route::get('/users/approve/{id}',[
        'uses' => 'Admin\UserController@getApprove',
        'as'   => 'admin.users.getApprove'
    ]);

    Route::get('/users/delete/{id}',[
        'uses' => 'Admin\UserController@getDelete',
        'as'   => 'admin.users.getDelete'
    ]);

});
```

I have also created Controller for the route above.

When I access `http://laravel.dev/admin` in AngularJs everything works perfectly, also when I **click** on `<a href="/admin/users"></a>` everything works as expected,

However if i manually refresh the browser when am at `http://laravel.dev/admin/users` I hit the controller directly and **no view** is returned

Presently am using this workaround in my Controller methods and will like something better, because it redirects back to base URL instead of loading page specified in URL

```
public function getIndex()
{
    if(!Request::ajax()) return redirect()->route('admin.home.getIndex');

    $user = User::all();
    return response()->json($user);
}
```

Comment: set htaccess to route all non asset or api calls to angular app entry point

Comment: do you have any working example ?

Comment: have you found any solution? I am facing the same please provide me your answer.

Comment: I am still using this in my controllers `public function getIndex() { if(!Request::ajax()) return redirect()->route('admin.home.getIndex'); $user = User::all(); return response()->json($user); }`

Comment: But I am looking for a way of doing this with .htaccess.. Will update you